# How to write username and password to logins.json, in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, password-management, firefox-profile

I have an application that launches a specific website in a specific Firefox profile in order to facilitate some actions.

The operator must then login on this website.  The application provides the username+password.

Is it possible, to store this username+password in the "saved passwords" file logins.json before launching Firefox?  I know that this data is normally encrypted, but I'm not trying to read it, I want to WRITE it.

Comment: That will be difficult. Here is a way to decrypt them, which can be useful if you want to understand how to encrypt them https://github.com/lclevy/firepwd & https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lclevy/firepwd/master/mozilla_pbe.pdf

Comment: Why not import them from a .csv created by your program. Much easier... https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/import-login-data-file

Comment: Do you have to use the version of Firefox that is already installed on the computer, or can you supply your own? If so, you can simply create the logins.json yourself without worrying about overwriting existing passwords.

Comment: @Gantendo, It needs to be automatic.  The idea is to save time.  The operator needs to do hundreds of these per hour.  Importing a username+password, isn't faster than copy&pasting it.  Can the import be done programmatically?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to do? You could in theory create a separate firefox installation that does not interfere if firefox is already installed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_Portable

Comment: @Gantendo It is OK to overwrite the logins.json.  But how to write the data in the file?  I look in the file, and I see for example the field "encryptedUsername".  Is it possible to replace this with a field "unencryptedUsername", or "username" ?

Comment: If it is OK to overwrite the logins.json file if it already exists on the computer, you can probably create that file once by saving the passwords the normal way and then copy it to every computer where your program is installed.... Using a portable version of Firefox ensures every install is the same (and that you won't overwrite someone's passwords).

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Gantendo I have one operator that manages a set of accounts for 100 clients. Each client has his own Firefox profile, and needs to login to 4-5 different websites.  We have a database of username+password for each client/website combination.  Currently the application helps the operator by allowing a 1-click launch, that opens the target website for the particular client (by launching the corresponding Firefox profile).  I want to know if I can help her more, by saving the username+password somewhere to avoid having to copy+paste it.

Comment: That one operator has only 1 computer, right? Maybe Greasemonkey could help autofill the password. Do you know JS?

Comment: You could store a list of clients with their credentials, have Greasemonkey load the entire list into memory, and then visit the correct website(s) and autofill the username+password. You'd probably need to make a simple interface with a "next client" and "next website" button. This is possible, and much easier than the original idea, but it requires decent JS knowledge. Downside is that Greasemonkey cannot switch Firefox profiles afaik, but I am not sure why that is necessary (and you could write a separate program to handle that task).

Comment: Yes, there is only 1 computer.  The firefox profiles are to avoid mixing cookies when we have multiple users accessing the same website.  Also each profile has a separate proxy configuration so each user has a unique IP.  Thanks for the suggestion about Greasemonkey, if it can be configured automatically that might be an option.  I can write JS.

Comment: In that case I would write a Greasemonkey script as described above, and a simple script (I love AutoIt) that switches profiles. The Greasemonkey script could, for example, signal that it is time to switch profiles by navigating to a page that has a title tag that contains the string "nextuser". The other script can detect that, and switch profiles. This is a bit hacky but it could work. The operator could have a very very simple interface; just a "NEXT" button would be enough.

Comment: I hope you are not spamming ;-)

Comment: @Gantendo Thanks for the suggestion, much appreciated.  I'm not spamming.  Betting on sports :)

Comment: Is there are reason you are not using an API? https://www.programmableweb.com/news/10-most-popular-gambling-apis/brief/2019/11/29 I never gamble, but I kinda assumed all betting websites would have APIs nowadays. https://the-odds-api.com/ You should probably google "firefox webdriver" https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox.html

Comment: @Gantendo It doesn't exist.  These APIs are price feeds, and often clunky scraped data. 
 There is no API that lets you reliably execute bets on the big bookmaker sites.  Exceptionally, Betfair has an API for the exchange, but that's an open market where people bid and offer against each other, not against the bookmaker.  Bookmakers make money from drunk casual bettors.  They lose money to people who crunch numbers and so if you consistently make money they will eventually shut down your account.  (Hence the need for 100 accounts.)

Comment: Fallout New Vegas taught me not to trust those casino guys https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TyY_hx0qn0

Comment: I see three tasks: Automate the account creation system (at least as much as possible) with a captcha solving service if required. Automate faking the "human-like" traffic. Automate placing the bets via a botnet. Shouldn't be too hard to do. Since you are claiming to have an infinite money making machine; let me know if you need help ;-)